# Is it possible to graph dotted or dashed lines?

Tags: vb.net, charts, series

**Simple Question:**

Is there a property for **Series** objects so that they graph as dashed lines? Something like this:

```
myChartControl.Series(0).LineStyle = SeriesLineStyle.Dashed
```

**Explanation:**

I am creating a line graph using the `Chart` control. The `Chart` has six `Series` objects, which it graphs.

The six series are all put on one graph and look like this:
[image]

By just looking at the graph, it is unclear that there are actually six graphed lines. There are basically **two sets of three** lines. I would like to use a dashed-line opposed to a solid line, so that the lines hidden by the other lines can be seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I use:

```
Dim mySeries As New Series
mySeries.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash
mySeries.BorderWidth = 2
mySeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StepLine
```